# Beginner issue re font

Tags: fonts

I'm learning LaTeX and I don't understand the following:

Why is it, that when I include the following line in the preamble, `\usepackage{times}`.
My Roman font changes to the Times font; however, when I include,
`\usepackage{arial}` or `\usepackage{sans}` (instead of the times package), the sans serif type fonts don't change.  In fact, they become Roman?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it not `\usepackage{uarial}` AFAIK. Then you should get arial fonts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file `times.sty` issues commands

```
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}
```

When used in `\usepackage{times}` whereas `sans` issues

```
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{cmss}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{cmr}
```

(which is computer modern roman). You can locate the respective `.sty` files and see what they are changing. For a detailed font management scheme see [this post by Alan Munn.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25249/3235)

Comment: Also, times has been superceded by [`mathptmx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathptmx).